Any way to make mouse auto-scroll scroll by lines similar to normal scroll wheel scroll?
When I use auto-scroll (by clicking middle mouse button, you see a new type of cursor that lets you smoothly scroll up down and also lets you control the speed depending how slow/fast you move your mouse up and down), it seems like it scroll lines at pixel level in screen. That is why it seems smooth.
While normal scroll wheel scrolls per line so it's not as smooth. Is there any way to make the auto-scroll also scroll per line (or the lines you define in mouse scroll settings) like normal scroll?
In other words, I want to make the auto-scroll speed constant like normal scroll. So it doesn't depend on how slow/fast I move mouse up/down.
